# Ubuntu 19.10 eating all my ram

Tags: ubuntu, memory

My ubuntu is super slow/laggy, I think it's because of the RAM consumption. It's a fresh Ubuntu 19.10 installation. This is what free and top say.

output of free is:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        7849916     4128680      444968     1415380     3276268     2008472
Swap:      16777212      921088    15856124
```

top says:

```
top - 15:54:28 up  1:01,  1 user,  load average: 1.08, 1.60, 1.93
top - 15:54:31 up  1:01,  1 user,  load average: 1.08, 1.60, 1.93
Tasks: 388 total,   2 running, 384 sleeping,   0 stopped,   2 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.8 us,  0.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 98.3 id,  0.2 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :   7665.9 total,   1423.0 free,   4316.3 used,   1926.6 buff/cache
MiB Swap:  16384.0 total,  15115.2 free,   1268.8 used.   2085.2 avail Mem 
top - 15:54:31 up  1:01,  1 user,  load average: 1.08, 1.60, 1.93
Tasks: 388 total,   2 running, 384 sleeping,   0 stopped,   2 zombie
%Cpu(s): 18.3 us,  4.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 77.5 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
top - 15:54:35 up  1:01,  1 user,  load average: 1.32, 1.64, 1.95
Tasks: 383 total,   1 running, 382 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  1.4 us,  1.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 95.0 id,  1.6 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :   7665.9 total,   1506.9 free,   4294.8 used,   1864.2 buff/cache
MiB Swap:  16384.0 total,  15137.5 free,   1246.5 used.   2064.5 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                            
  205 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  12.9   0.0   0:23.83 kswapd0                                                                                                            
 5087 andreas   20   0 1322040 285068 214012 S  10.9   3.6  13:40.59 Xorg                                                                                                               
 5313 andreas   20   0 3652472 270792  82232 S   7.3   3.4   6:12.85 gnome-shell                                                                                                        
 8562 andreas   20   0  897404  49848  28552 S   5.0   0.6   0:11.73 gnome-terminal-                                                                                                    
  398 root      19  -1  517344 304704 303040 S   3.0   3.9   0:36.18 systemd-journal                                                                                                    
 6478 andreas   20   0 3891768 150120  35832 S   2.0   1.9   2:29.38 spotify                                                                                                            
 5048 andreas    9 -11 2860792  19372  14408 S   1.7   0.2   1:37.86 pulseaudio                                                                                                         
14423 andreas   20   0   30720   2272   1428 S   1.7   0.0   0:21.52 htop                                                                                                               
    1 root      20   0  168440  11296   7620 S   1.0   0.1   0:18.74 systemd                                                                                                            
   84 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3   0.0   0:04.16 kauditd                                                                                                            
   94 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.3   0.0   0:04.24 kworker/u24:1-events_unbound                                                                                       
 5540 andreas   20   0  163000   6880   6260 S   0.3   0.1   0:02.10 ibus-engine-sim                                                                                                    
 6327 andreas   20   0 1315172 333320 243684 S   0.3   4.2   3:47.08 chrome                                                                                                             
 9304 mysql     20   0 2239460  48356   6104 S   0.3   0.6   0:08.08 mysqld                                                                                                             
12694 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.3   0.0   0:00.78 kworker/11:1-events                                                                                                
14820 andreas   20   0  614960 125716  65392 S   0.3   1.6   0:47.86 chrome                                                                                                             
16366 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.3   0.0   0:00.10
```

any ideas, suggestions, recommandations?

Comment: Additional information request. 
# cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: output from top -o RES please